# TypeScript: Factory method - incorrect extends, types returned incompatible

Tags: typescript-generics

Again spending way too much time with correct typings and was wondering whether such thing is possible without compiler throwing error of incorrect base class extension, even tho it correctly recognizes returned type (see the last line):

```js
class Parent {
    static create<T extends Parent>(Cls: new () => T): T {
        return new Cls();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static create() {
        return super.create(Child);
    }
}

const inst = Child.create();    // correct type of "Child"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6EaYaAlsNMMsUgDwAq0SAHmqgCYzzLoB8AFAGEQEAFzQUSAO7Q+ASmgBeHtDqyxDHPi3RkaAK4IU4qdCEQ5Ablz4AvtjvZQkGAIAWJEG0Yt2nRKgxNfEJiMgoqVjksa20dJH1DAj0AByQEADpKJGpBd09ZKy07B2AAexRCaBIKjAVTPLZMiKRLLQB6NopShGRgDDQAT1ToUoAzaAAiNw82CewgA)

Error thrown:

```
Class static side 'typeof Child' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Parent'.
  The types returned by 'create(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Child' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'Child' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Parent'.
```

How to tell compiler, that returned type will be the same type as Cls parameter? I'm kinda newbie in TS, but I'd say I don't need generics as I have the type of the created object passed as parameter, so I know exactly the type.

Answer (score 0):

Over here TypeScript compiler is trying to match up the two `static` methods. Even though you are ensuring that the return types match up, Typescript doesn't know that for sure. You can think of it in a way where each distinct invocation of `Parent::create` creates a different method in `Parent`. One for `Child` which extends for `Parent`, but there could be `AnotherChild` that extends from `Parent`. And `Child` could be not assignable to the other subtype and that's why the compiler complains.

I believe it'd be just easier to remove the generic code and do something like -

```
class Parent {
    static create(Cls: new () => Parent): Parent {
        return new Cls();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static create() : Child {
        return super.create(Child);
    }
}

const inst = Child.create();    // correct type of "Child"
```

As `Child` is  already extending from `Parent`, `Child::create` over here is perfectly valid now.

Comment: thanks for commenting on this! your solution would solve the error, but would return Parent type upon calling `Parent.create(Child)`